# Alternative methods of locating function offsets for use as function pointer?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, reverse-engineering

When writing code that is to be injected into a running process, and subsequently call functions from within that application, sometimes you need to create a function pointer if you're wanting to call a function provided by that application itself - in the manner of a computer-based training application, or a computer game hack, etc.

Function pointers are easy in C++, if you know the offset of the function. Finding those offsets are what become the time consuming part, if the application that you're working with is frequently updated, because updates to the application may change the offset.

Are there any methods of automatically tracking these offsets? I seem to recall hearing about fingerprinting methods or something that would attempt to automatically locate the functions for you. Any ideas about those?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478942/re-ida-finding-function-offset

Comment: Not the same thing. I can locate things in IDA, no problem. The problem is, once located I have an offset, but if the program is updated then the offset might change. I'm just wondering if there are any techniques for locating functions if their address has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is very dependent on what you're injecting into and the environment you're running.

If you're in a windows environment, i'd give this a read through 
[x86 code injection into an x86 proccess from a x64 process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297452/x86-code-injection-into-an-x86-process-from-a-x64-process)

In a linux type environment you could do something with the global offset table?

You could always do signature based approach to find the function. Or perhaps there is an exported function that calls the function you want to hook. You could trace the logic as such.